# How to Consistently Return 2.5% of a Result Set using NEWID() and Table Variable?

Tags: t-sql

I'm using the NEWID() approach to obtain a sample of records from my population.  I've created a table variable to define my population and I need to consistently return 2.5% of records from it.  The query is as follows:

```
DECLARE @FirstofLastMonth date = DATEADD(DD,1,EOMONTH(Getdate(),-2)), 
@EndofLastMonth date =  EOMONTH(Getdate(), -1)

DECLARE @Sample table  (ID uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY, ClaimNO varchar(50), Company_ID 
varchar(10), FinancialResp varchar(30), ProviderType varchar(50), 
DateOfService date, ClaimType varchar(20), TotalBilled numeric(10,2), TotalPaid numeric(10,2) )
Insert into @Sample (ID, ClaimNo,Company_ID, FinancialResp, ProviderType, DateOfService, 
ClaimType, TotalBilled, TotalPaid)
Select distinct NEWID() as ID,  cd.ClaimNo, cd.Company_ID, cd.FinancialResp,
CASE
when cd.FinancialResp in ('KEYMA', 'SHP', 'SFKD') and lob.LOB_Network = '1' then 'Contracted'
when cd.FinancialResp in ('KEYMA', 'SHP', 'SFKD') and lob.LOB_Network = '0' then 'Non-Contracted'
when cd.FinancialResp = 'KDMA' and pu.UDF_Value = 'Y' then 'Contracted' 
when cd.FinancialResp = 'KDMA' and pu.UDF_Value <> 'Y' then 'Non-Contracted'
else 'Missing'
end as ProviderType,
Format( Min(cd.FromDateSvc), 'MM/dd/yyyy') as DateOfService, 
CASE 
when substring(cd.ClaimNo, 9,1) = '8' then 'Institutional'
when substring(cd.ClaimNO, 9,1) = '9' then 'Professional'
end as Claim_Type,
sum(cd.Billed) as TotalBilled,
SUM(cd.Net) as TotalPaid
from Claim_Details cd 
inner join Claim_Masters_V cm on cd.ClaimNo = cm.ClaimNo and cd.Company_ID = cm.Company_ID
inner join Prov_VendInfo pv on cm.Prov_KeyID = pv.Prov_KeyID and cm.Company_ID = pv.Company_ID
inner join Vend_Masters vm on pv.Vendor = vm.VendorID 
            and pv.Company_ID = vm.Environment_ID
inner join Prov_Master_V pm on cm.Prov_KeyID = pm.Prov_KeyID 
            and cm.Company_ID = pm.Company_ID
            and pv.Default_YN = 1
inner join BM_Prov_HP_LineOfBuss lob on cm.Prov_KeyID = lob.Prov_KeyID
            and cm.Company_ID = lob.Company_ID
            and cm.HPCode = lob.HPCode
            and pv.Vendor = lob.Vendor
            and lob.LOB_Start <= GETDATE()
left join Prov_UDF pu on cm.Prov_KeyID = pu.Prov_KeyID
            and cm.Company_ID = pu.Company_ID
            and pu.UDFNO = 10
where cm.HPCode = 'KD'
and cd.Status = '9'
and cd.FromDateSvc between @FirstofLastMonth and @EndofLastMonth
group by cd.ClaimNo, cd.FinancialResp, cd.Company_ID, pu.UDF_Value, lob.LOB_Network

--Select Count(*)
--from @Sample  --3,517 records 

select ClaimNo, FinancialResp, ProviderType, DateOfService, ClaimType, TotalBilled, TotalPaid  from @Sample 
WHERE 0.025 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(),ID) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
--We need to receive ~88 records each time above query is run.
```

When I run the above query, my results vary from between 80 and 100 records.  The business case requires just 2.5% of qualifying records to be returned, no more and no less.  How do I ensure that this is always the case, all things being equal?

**UPDATE**
I've modified the approach a bit.  I'm now loading all qualifying records into a table.  I've refined the query which now returns the required 2.5% of the table population.  However, each time I run the query, the results do not appear to be random samples in that the same RecordIDs are returned each time.

```
    select TOP 2.5 PERCENT RecordID, ClaimNo, HPCode, 
    FinancialResponsibility, ProviderType, ProcessorType, DateOfService, 
    DatePaid, ClaimType, TotalBilled, TotalPaid  
    from [Z_Monthly_Quality_Review]  
    order by RecordId
```

The table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Z_Monthly_Quality_Review] (
  [RecordId]                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
  [ClaimNO]                 VARCHAR (50)     NULL,
  [Company_ID]              VARCHAR (10)     NULL,
  [HPCode]                  VARCHAR (10)     NULL,
  [FinancialResponsibility] VARCHAR (30)     NULL,
  [ProviderType]            VARCHAR (50)     NULL,
  [DateOfService]           DATE             NULL,
  [DatePaid]                DATE             NULL,
  [ClaimType]               VARCHAR (50)     NULL,
  [TotalBilled]             NUMERIC (11, 2)  NULL,
  [TotalPaid]               NUMERIC (11, 2)  NULL,
  [ProcessorType]           VARCHAR (100)    NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RecordId] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)
 );
```

Should I modify the query or table structure in order to consistently return a 2.5% random sample (different RecordIDs each time its run) of the table data?

Comment: Couldn't you just use SELECT TOP 2.5 PERCENT * FROM @Sample ORDER BY ID

Comment: @JMabee Possibly.  However, I have to ensure that it's a random sample.  Would your approach ensure this?

Comment: Yes, you are still using GUIDs.

Comment: @JMabee Thanks for your suggestion.  It appears that random GUIDs are returned.  How do I ensure that exactly 2.5% sample size is returned consistently?  If TSQL cannot do this, is PowerBI or SSRS the better approach?

Comment: Well again, you are using GUIDs so there is not much worry about TIES so TSQL. If you are concerned about the exact number it is going to return then I would suggest you do a quick test using a tally table to figure out the number of rows returned for a given number of rows in your tally table.  That will tell you how exact TSQL is going to be.